# <a href> with image is disable in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, html, google-chrome

hey, i have a .net C# function thats write html image links code such as:

```
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
```

and show it by **asp:literal**,

it works fine in Explorer and Firefox but in chrome the clicking is disable,
any ideas?

example code:

```
<div class=\"whitebox\" style=\"width:500px;\">
    <div style=\"float:left;\">
        <a href=\"../reader/Default.aspx?u=4&t=2&sr=f-53D\">    
        <img width=\"75px\" height=\"75px\" src=\"http://www.Knu.com/main.jpg\" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That should work fine.  Show us your actual HTML... the HTML that is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I can see with that is if you're somehow outputting it exactly like that, with the C# escaping included.